# How to access parent resource block value in the child resource block?

Tags: azure, terraform

Here I want to create service bus with queue,topic & subcription in azure ,  so I want to access parent resource block value of **topic_id** with contains for_each loop
resource from child block of code which its already having for_each?

```
"azurerm_servicebus_topic" "default" {
resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "default" {
  name                = var.resource_name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.current.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.current.name
  sku                 = var.sku
  capacity            = var.capacity
  tags                = var.resource_tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags,
      location
    ]
  }

}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "default" {
  for_each            = toset(var.queues)
  name                = each.value
  namespace_id        = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.default.id
  enable_partitioning = var.enable_partitioning
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "default" {
  for_each            = toset(var.topics)
  name                = each.value
  namespace_id        = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.default.id
  enable_partitioning = var.enable_partitioning
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "default" {
  for_each           = toset(var.servicebus_subscription)
  name               = each.value
  topic_id           = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key]
  max_delivery_count = var.max_delivery_count
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
topics          = ["test001"]
queues          = ["test00_queue"]
ip_rules = []
virtual_network_subnet_ids = []
servicebus_subscription=["tf-sub"]
```

**FYI: I'm able to create topic but error thronging from subscription creation time**

Comment: `azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key].id`!? But obviously only if `topics` and `servicebus_subscription` actually have any relation to each other. Given the variables.tf that does not seem to be the case raising the question what you actually want to achieve and why and how? If you only create a single subscription and no topic what topic should the subscription use?

Comment: **azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key].id** , use the same as well but didn't work. And there is relation between topic & subscription.

Comment: There is no relation shown. You currently have 0 topics but 1 subscription configured based on the `variables.tf`. How is that supposed to ever work??

Comment: Use `count` instead of `for_each`.

Comment: actually using count will solve my problem but i may have to increase list subscription in future so i should use for each

Comment: If you have lists and need to correlate them based on the index then you need to use `count`. If you have a different way to correlate the two you need to make it explicit by not using lists but objects / dictionaries instead.

Comment: In the place for_each I use count but throughs an error │ Error: Missing resource instance key
│
│   on ../../main.tf line 50, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "default":
│   50:   topic_id           = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default.id
│
│ Because azurerm_servicebus_topic.default has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key]

Answer (score 0):

> How to access parent resource block value in the child resource block:

"ID" (`topic_id`) should be passed for`azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key]`  as `azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key].id` because `each.key` doesn't not accept `topic_id` value which is the ID of the service bus topic to create it in a given subscription.

***I made below changes to your code and was able to successfully create a service bus namespace in the given subscription.***

```bash
resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "default" {
  for_each           = toset(["topic1","topic2"])
  name               = each.value
  topic_id           = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key].id
  max_delivery_count = 1
}
```

`terraform init`:

[image]

`terraform plan`:

[image]

`terraform apply`:

[image]

[image]

***Deployed in portal without creation time errors:***

[image]

`Service Bus namespace -> Queues`:

[image]

`Service Bus namespace -> Topics`:

[image]

Comment: here subscription names & topic name should same? if its same works for me with above code or else thronging  an error below

 Error: Invalid index
│
│   on ../../main.tf line 55, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "default":
│   55:   topic_id = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_servicebus_topic.default is object with 1 attribute "tf1"
│     │ each.key is "topic1"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵

Comment: Make sure that you are giving similar names otherwise it throws an error mentioning key not found in the collection rule.

Comment: subscriptions and topics are able to create with different names in portal, so why can't is working same name with terraform?

Comment: What is the error showing for that?

Comment: error: Invalid index │ │ on ../../main.tf line 55, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "default": │ 55: topic_id = azurerm_servicebus_topic.default[each.key].id │ ├──────────────── │ │ azurerm_servicebus_topic.default is object with 1 attribute "tf1" │ │ each.key is "topic1" │ │ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value

Comment: What is the default value you are providing for topics in var.tf?

Comment: variable "topics" {
  description = "List of topic to be created. Changing this forces new topics to be created"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}

Comment: Instead of giving it in a separate variable file try passing in the `main.tf` itself.